# Cognate to English "rut"?

Tags: etymology

Wieso steht *räudig* in keinem Wörterbuch mit der Bedeutung von Läufigkeit bei Hunden?

1. Alle scheinen davon auszugehen, dass *räudiger Köter* im Ursprung für ein krankes Tier steht. *Räude* ist laut Pfeifer ungewisser Herkunft, eventuell  "einer Dentalerweiterung der Wurzel ie. **kreu(ə)-* ‘dickes, stockendes Blut, rohes Fleisch’" ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/R%c3%a4ude)), vgl. polnisch *krew* "Blut" usw., das sicherlich nicht rein zufällig *Krätze* ähnelt, die aber naiv mit *kratzen* erklärt werden kann, was dahinstehen mag, weil sich das lautmalerische Wort der regelhaften Analyse entzieht.
2. Ich mag mich ja irren, da ich mich nicht erinnern kann, das Wort je mit einer sachlichen Bedeutung gehört zu haben ("Da ist meine räudige Nachbarin"). Hundskrätze ist aber auch eher selten geworden, Straßenköter sowieso.

   Tatsächlich lässt sich der Zusammenhang (m.M.n.) noch aus der Bezeichnung *Rüde* erschließen. Zur Morphologie: Wie nennt man einen Hund, der räudig ist? Na sicher nicht *Räude*.
3. Laut Pfeifer ist die Herkunft wiederum ungewiss. Die älteste nachweisbare Bedeutung betrifft irgendeinen großen Hund, so Grimm (DWB: *rüde*). D.h. das Tier ist möglicherweise erwachsen und geschlechtsreif.

[image: Etymological Dictionary of Proto-Germanic By Guus Kroonen. BRILL: LEIDEN, BOSTON. 2013]

4. Jedenfalls heißt englisch *rut* genau *Brunst*, bzw. *Brunft*, so auch der Brunftruf des Hirsches, dies wohl über französisch, letztendlich lautmalerisch. Kroonen (Etymological Dictionary of Proto-Germanic) verhandelt *Rüde* jedoch derart, dass der Zusammenhang mit *räudig* wahrscheinlich sein dürfte.

   Ein vergleichbares Beispiel wäre griechisch κάπρος, καπράω, καπρίζω, καπρῴζομαι (cf. [Frisk](https://lsj.gr/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%AC%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%82#Frisk_Etymology_German)). Da die Etymologie ungeklärt ist, hilft das nicht viel.
5. Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch leitet englisch *rut* über altfranzösisch *ruit* (mfr. *rut*) aus *rūgitus* ab. Schlüssig ist das nicht. Nicht nur sind die Lautwandel zweifelhaft (s. z.B. FN 12); sowieso ist die entsprechende Bedeutung erst im 9. Jh. nachweisbar (pg. [559](https://lecteur-few.atilf.fr/index.php/page/lire/e/226066)). Somit ist ein Verhältnis zu germanischen Sprachen kaum auszuschließen.

Außerdem denke ich da an *Rudel, rattig, rollig sein*, *ranzig werden*, *raunen, röhren*, *rödeln*, *riechen*, en. *crude, rude*, *horny*, *randy*, *rowdy*. Problematisch ist wie so oft, wenn Tabuthemen der Schriftsprache eher fern bleiben.

Zur Frage gestellt werden dementsprechend Alt- bzw. Sondersprachen, etwa Jägersprache, ob der Begriff dort bekannt ist, die Beleidigung davon abgeleitet ist und entweder mit dem Krankheitsbild vermischt wurde, oder sogar auf einen gemeinsamen Ursprung zurück geht.

Also nochmal zum mitmeißeln:

1. Steht *räudig* in irgendeiner Lehn- oder Verwandschaftsbeziehung zu englisch *rut*?
2. Insofern *rut* in Beziehung zu *Rüde* steht, kann man genauso gut fragen, ob *räudig* in irgendeiner Lehn- oder Verwandschaftsbeziehung zu *Rüde steht*.

Es wäre sachdienlich anzunehmen, dass eine positive Antwort durch vereinzelte Belege nachweisbar ist, die mir bisher entgangen sind. Für eine negative Antwort gilt im Grunde dasselbe.

**PS**: Weil einige Ruhmredige nicht richtig lesen können, handelt diese Frage nun scheinbar von *Räude*. Es schließt zwar das Vorhandensein der einen Ableitung die andere nicht aus, insbesondere wenn anderes nicht sicher geklärt ist, so dass man fragen muss, **kommt *räudig* eventuel nicht von *räudig*?**, aber das hat die Volksetymologie noch nie interessiert. Und somit wird aus einer gewagten Vermutung (s. Kluge/Seebold, Pfeifer, Olschansky) plötzlich ein reines Gewissen. Gewissheit verschaft mir das mit Sicherheit nicht.

> Räude ist Eine Hautkrankheit, die in erster Linie Haustiere betrifft. Den *räudigen Hund* kennt man auch als Beschimpfung. Man mag an *rauhe* oder *gerötete* Haut denken und sich das Wort durch *rauh* oder *Röte* zu erklären versuchen. Sprachlich besteht da allerdings kein Zusammenhang.

> *Räude* (mittelhochdeutsch *riude, rūde*, althochdeutsch *(h)hriuþi, rūda*) ist in seiner Herkunft nicht geklärt. **Vermutet** wird eine Grundlage ‘rohes Fleisch u. ä.’ (indogermanisch **krewa-*)

> (Heike Olschansky, Täuschende Wörter: Kleines Lexikon der Volksetymologien, Reclam, 2009)

Unter diesen Umständen sind die bisher gegebenen Antworten (@user52445, @HubertSchölnast) unmöglich zu akzeptieren.

Answer (score 6):

> Wieso steht räudig in keinem Wörterbuch mit der Bedeutung von Läufigkeit bei Hunden?

Weil das Wort diese Bedeutung nicht hat.

Sehr wahrscheinlich kanntest du das Wort nicht, als du ihm erstmals begegnet bist, und hast dir eine Bedeutung aus dem Kontext zu erschließen versucht, die unzutreffend ist. Nun versuchst du Belege für dieses Missverständnis zu finden.

Nur weil Wörter ähnlich klingen, müssen sie nicht etymologisch miteinander verwandt sein, schon gar nicht, wenn die ähnlich klingenden Wörter aus unterschiedlichen Sprachen stammen.

Engl. *rut* "Brunft" stammt über mittelfrz. *rut* "Brunft" < altfrz. *ruit* "Brunft" < spätlat. *rugitus* "Röhren" < lat. *rūgīre* "röhren", das wiederum vermutlich aus einer indoeuropäischen Wurzel abgeleitet ist, die "(Laute, Luft) ausstoßen" bedeutet haben könnte und mit gr. *ἐρεύγεσθαι* /eré͞ugesthai/ "rülpsen" verwandt ist. (Quelle: OED, s.v. *rut* n.1, https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/169155)

Dt. *Räude* und *räudig* dagegen stammen von einer germanischen Wurzel ab, die soviel wie "Kruste, Rinde, Schorf, unfruchtbarer Boden" bedeutet haben dürfte. (Quelle: DWDS, s.v. Räude, https://www.dwds.de/wb/R%C3%A4ude)

Wie du nun darauf kommst, dass *rut* und *Räude* zwangsläufig miteinander verwandt sein sollen, erschließt sich mir nicht.

Im Übrigen vermischst du *Räude* und *Rüde* auf unzulässige Weise. Beide Wörter haben außer lautlichen Ähnlichkeiten nichts miteinander zu tun. Räude tritt bei unterschiedlichen Tieren auf, nicht nur bei Hunden (s. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A4ude). Diese Bedeutung ("scabies") ist bereits seit dem Ahd. nachgewiesen (s. https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/raude).

Answer (score 0):

Das Adjektiv *räudig* steht zum Substantiv *Räude* in einer ähnlichen Beziehung wie *syphilitisch* zu *Syphilis* und *grippal* zu *Grippe.* Es sind einfach Adjektive, die vom Namen einer Krankheit angeleitet wurden.

Die Herkunft des Substantivs *Räude* hast du ja bereits selbst recherchiert. Es stammt von *riudi* bzw. *ruda* und bezeichnet eine aus getrocknetem Blut bestehende Kruste auf der Haut.

Ich bin der Steiermark aufgewachsen, dort spricht man einen südost-bayrischen Dialekt, der meine eigentliche Muttersprache ist (Standarddeutsch habe ich erst in der Schule gelernt), und das Vokabel für die dunklen Krusten, die sich im Zuge der Heilung von Schürfwunden auf der Haut bilden, lautet in meiner Muttersprache *»Raun«* oder *»Raudn«* wobei das *d* mehr gedacht als wirklich gesprochen wird (so wie das *d* in *reden,* das in der Umgangssprache auch oft nicht zu hören ist). Dieses Wort entstammt, wie ich stark vermute, derselben Wurzel wie das standarddeutsche Wort *»Räude«.*

*Räude* ist eine Krankheit, die laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A4ude) bei 104 verschiedenen Säugetierarten auftritt. Außer bei Hunden, Katzen und Füchsen tritt sie auch bei Pferden, Ziegen und Schafen auf. Viele dieser Erkrankungen können vom Tier auf den Menschen überspringen, aber es gibt auch eine Unterart der Räude, die nur Menschen befällt. Sie heißt [Krätze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kr%C3%A4tze) und ist noch immer nicht ausgerottet. Räude und Krätze wird von Milben hervorgerufen, die knapp unter der Haut leben und auf der Oberfläche dunklen Krusten verursachen, die jenen ähneln, die auch durch Schürfwunden entstehen.

Ich sehe keinen Grund anzunehmen, dass der Name einer Hautkrankheit, die über 100 verschiedene Spezies befällt, bei einer einzigen dieser Tierarten in Zusammenhang mit sexuellen Aktivitäten stehen soll. Daher ist für mich auch völlig verständlich, dass eine Bedeutung, die es weder in der Vergangenheit noch in der Gegenwart gibt, in keinem Wörterbuch steht.

Zusammenhänge mit *Rüde, Rudel, rattig, rollig, ranzig* und anderen Wörter, die nur verbindet, dass sie mit einem R beginnen, gibt es nicht.

Answer (score 0):

1. David Dalby (Lexicon of the Mediaeval German Hunt, Berlin: de Gruyter; 1965) glossiert *rüde, rude* (Hervorhebung im Original)

   > mastiff, dog (as opposed to “hound”) i.e. large, rough dog used for the running down of game; similarly **rüdischer hunt**; also **swīn-rüde**: mastiff used for boar-hunting.

   mit Zitaten,: "... ich hüet des wildes vor rüedischen hunden" (Hadamar 45), "swenn ez (das wilt) sīn dan erbītet, / so hetzt er rüden dran und vāhtz in seilen." (Hadamar 213), s. [Hadamar von Laber](https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&query=100817602) ca. 14. Jh.; daneben unter anderem *vreche rüden* (Parzival 281, 3). Ob darin ein semantischer Unterschied auszumachen ist, wird nicht gesagt.
2. August Lübben (Mittelniederdeutsches Handwörterbuch, August Lübben, 1818-1884; Christoph Walther, 1841-1914 [Herausgeber], Verein für niederdeutsche Sprachforschung) führt an

   - *rode, rodde* "*sw. m.* 1. *großer Hund, Rüde*, molossus"

   in Zusammensetzung bspw.

   - *roden-dage* "*Hundstage*", *roden-dreck* "*Hundeexcremente*, album graecum"

   und mehr (pg. [304](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/view/bsb11023642?page=318)), nämlich zu unterscheiden von *rude* "*Räude*", *rudich, ruderig* "*räudig, schorfig*", *rudichtich* bzw. *rudicheit* "*Räude, Schorf*" (pg. [309](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/view/bsb11023642?page=323)).

   Übrigens steht neben echten Homophonen zu *rode* eine botanische Bedeutung, "2.  »*Läufer*«, *Zapfen-Hopfen*, lupulus femina", die offenbar als Lehnübersetzung (s. lateinisch *lupus* "Wolf", *lupulus* "Hopfen", diminutiv "Wölfchen") zu *rode* gezählt wird.

Das belegt einerseits die Semantik (*vreche rüden*, *roden-dage*), die wegen der üblichen Konnotation bei *räudiger Hund* ohnehin zu erwarten war. Andererseits bestätigen mittelhochdeutsch *rüdisch* und mittelniederdeutsch *roden-* die Vermutung einer adjektivischen Form, wobei die Bedeutung über das Übliche hinaus unklar bleibt.

Ob ferner Anschluss an die Sippe um *Brunft*, En. *rut* usw. denkbar ist (wie Kroonen fordert) oder ob etwa *räudig* strikt davon zu unterscheiden ist (wie es bei Olschansky im weiteren den Anschein machen wird), bleibt fraglich.

[*Fortsetzung folgt*]